# BluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices is not finding any devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-development

I am trying to find my connected devices via the BluetoothManager class as I read on developer.android.com. I used the line below to obtain a list of connected devices:

```
System.out.println(bluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothGatt.GATT).toString());
```

However, it is just returning an empty array. I gave my app Bluetooth and Bluetooth_Admin permissions in the manifest file, so I dont think there are any problems with permissions.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following; it should help as it attempts to get connected devices who's current status (or profile) is `STATE_CONNECTED`:

```
System.out.println(bluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED).toString());
```

Read here for more:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile

Comment: It throws the following exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Profile not supported: 2`